# Locking translation on nodes that have been manually modified so that someone doesn't accidentally overwrite them with a TMGMT import

Tags: drupal, multilingual, crowdin

We use the TMGMT Crowdin plugin to translate the content on our website, but sometimes after a translation is done someone internal to the company wants to change the wording of one of the translated pages to make it more fitting for the interests of people from that specific country.

When this happens, and the English node gets updated occasionally someone will request full translation again and the modified node will get overwritten.

Is there a way to lock translation on a specific node so that it can't accidentally get overwritten by an import from Crowdin?

I've read through the docs a bit and think a custom module might be able to solve the problem but I am hoping there is a built in way to handle this scenario.